# python Grab проблема с установкой

Tags: python

Проблема с установкой библиоткеи Grab.

pip3 install Grab

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как можно исправить ? не устанавливается... это с ОС что то не так или сама библиотека уже не работает чтоле ? не понимаю...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Судя по ошибке, у вас проблема с установкой `pycurl`. На английском СО [пишут](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24051044/8324991), что в этом случае может помочь такая установка пакетов:

```
sudo apt install libcurl4-openssl-dev libssl-dev
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Помогло!

Comment: Тогда отметьте ответ как правильный, чтобы воврос не показывался как не отвеченный